# Building CoreCLR on a 32 bit Windows?

Tags: .net, build

Is it possible to build CoreCLR for the x86 architecture? It doesn't seem to be possible to build it for x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as of writing this answer, no.

The [developer guide](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/wiki/Developer-Guide) specifies this:

> CoreCLR repo can be built from a regular, non-admin command prompt.
>   Currently, the repo supports building CoreCLR.dll (and its various
>   native binaries), mscorlib.dll and the accompanying tests for the
>   following platforms and build configurations:
>
> Windows:
>
> - X64 - Debug and Release

But i'd watch out for updates as the releases come.